# Create actionsheet similar to Contacts app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiactionsheet

In one of my application, i want to create actionsheet similar to default contacts app. I am little bit confused about how to create this screen, is it default actionsheet provided by iOS or is it any custom screen. If it is default actionsheet, then how to implement **multiline** action as it is in following screen

[image]

Comment: have a look at [XLActionController](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLActionController).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a system action sheet with private api.

According to [Apple official document for `UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller)

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Because custom system action sheet is illegal so I'm pretty sure that you can't archive something like this by using system action sheet

You can create it yourself by an `UIViewController` with `UIStackView` or `UITableView`.

If you want some libraries, take a look at [action sheet on Cocoa](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=actionsheet)

Comment: it means apple himself is not using their default controls.. and making custom ones... :)

Comment: it was looking almost similar to actionsheet, thats why i doubted.. otherwise making custom one is the last option...

Comment: Oh sorry, if it's an Apple app, they did it with private api which we can't use. The answer is still no if you want to using system action sheet ;)